# Confirmation email link loaded by Outlook causing double confirmation

Tags: java, html, email, spring-mvc, outlook

I've run into a bit of an issue with Outlook where I'm sending a confirmation email to activate a new account to an Outlook email address but Outlook is loading the URL in the email, thus activating the account. Once the user clicks the links, he gets and error because the account is already activated.

Is there any way to prevent this?

I'm using Spring MVC 3 with Wildfly9. I'm just creating a standard email. I'm not injecting any HTML. I've added a workaround but would like to figure out how to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this before too, but only when the user has a third party spam filter which checks (and loads) every link in incoming emails. If this is the case, there's nothing we can do as developers to stop it happening.

I don't know what your workaround already is, but I'd suggest either:

- Allowing a second click of the link without displaying an error to the user. (If you are happy with the security implications of a user potentially not knowing their activation link has already been clicked by somebody/something.)

or ideally

- Requiring a user action after loading the activation link - such as the user confirming their password, or even just clicking a 'confirm' button on the web page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I did go for option 1 but I do very much like option 2. I might change it to that. Seems like Outlook webmail might have this spam filter. I haven't been having any issues with Gmail.